# Вложенный SELECT метода IN в EntityFramework linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

### Есть класс User:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;};
    public string Surname {get;set;};
}
```

### Также, есть класс Order

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string UsrId {get;set;}
    public User Usr {get;set;}
    public double bill {get;set;}
}
```

### И контекст данных

```
public class AppContext : DbContext 
{
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

---

В месте вызова определен контекст

```
var db = new AppContext();
```

Получаю конкретных пользователей по условию:

```
var usrs = db.Users.Where(u=>u.Name=="Иван");
```

Необходимо получить все заявки, которые содержатся в таблице `Orders`, где Order.UsrId совпадает со **списком** пользователей `usrs`

---

Я знаю как это сделать через обычный SQL запрос:

```
select * from Orders where Orders.UsrId in (select Id from Users where Name=N'Иван')
```

> Как это сделать через linq запрос?
>   Пробовал что-то типа

```
var ords = db.Orders.Where(o=>o.Id==..... 
// и вот тут не могу понять как сопоставить множеству Id из выборки usrs
```

Comment: А как это к пользователям применить?

Comment: Я не знаю, что вы понимаете под "как применить к пользователям", уточните, какую именно выборку вы хотите сделать. Вот тут было понятно: `Необходимо получить все заявки, которые содержатся в таблице Orders, где Order.UsrId совпадает со списком пользователей usrs`, а сейчас слишком кратко описываете задачу.

Comment: Большое спасибо! То что надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
void Main()
{
    var orders = new List<Order>();
    orders.Add(new Order { Id = 1, UsrId = 1 });
    orders.Add(new Order { Id = 2, UsrId = 2 });
    orders.Add(new Order { Id = 3, UsrId = 2 });
    orders.Add(new Order { Id = 4, UsrId = 3 });
    orders.Add(new Order { Id = 5, UsrId = 1 });

    var subset = new[] { 1, 3};

    var result = orders.Where(x => subset.Any(y => y == x.UsrId));

    result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UsrId { get; set; }
}
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]